# Can I use pointers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, pointers, hook

Is there any way I can hook an element onclick event to a variable?

If I change the variable, will the onclick event be updated too? Why isn't it so?

When I'm writing a frame, sometimes I have some buttons in different parts of the page, but these buttons hook to a same event function.

When I want to change the event function, I have to change all these button's events!

Can I do something like this?

```
var publicFunc = function(){console.log('aaa');},
    button1 = document.getElementById('button1'),
    button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
button1.onclick = publicFunc;
button2.onclick = publicFunc;

//i hope when i change publicFunc, all onclick event change
publicFunc = function(){console.log('bbb');};
//how to tell all the buttons this event function has changed?!
//i hope button1.onclick now is "function(){console.log('bbb');};"
//but of course it's "function(){console.log('aaa');};"
//is there any smart way to change it to "bbb"???
```

The first thought came to me is to find a way to use a pointer in Javascript like in C/C++, but after hard search, I find few information about that.

Comment: **NO** By doing `publicFunc = function()` you overwrite the reference of the `publicFunc` variable but not the previous function that was set to `onclick`. ;)

Comment: i'm not sure if it is my bad expression...i hope find a way to make onclick event link to "a pointer point to another var" than "a certain value".

Comment: **YES/NO** Functions are just like any other variables in JS. You can store them to variables, pass them to functions and return them from other functions. However, there are no C++ style references in JavaScript. See my answer (and James's)

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why this got downvoted so hard.  I don't think it's a bad question.

Comment: @JamesMontagne It's because people didn't understand what the OP was asking, then once someone sees a downvote, it's all downhill from there

Comment: @JuanMendes  Yeah, I guess you're right.  Probably combined with a knee-jerk reaction to the title.

Comment: so i edited my post to make my point more clear...and thank u guys' help a lot.

Comment: @JuanMendes, i picked the one that show on top... sorry that have to pick one. both answers are useful and helpful. thx!

Comment: @Maplemx Don't worry, they say the same thing. James beat me by a few seconds. I was going to delete my answer but decided to add another example to help clarify the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `button2.onclick = publicFunc;`, you are assigning the function to the `.onclick` property, not the variable.  As a result, when you assign a new function to that variable, the `.onclick` is not affected.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you will need a second function.  Your handlers call this second function which you can replace.

http://jsfiddle.net/jre2N/1/

```
var changeable = function () {
    console.log("aaaa");
};
var publicFunc = function () {
    changeable();
};

var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
button1.onclick = publicFunc;
button2.onclick = publicFunc;

//change the behavior
changeable = function () {
    console.log('bbb');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem with terminology, that is, pointers vs references. There's no way to emulate C++ references in JavaScript as you would like.

That is, you cannot change one variable and affect other references to it.

To solve your problem, you could do the following

```
var publicFunc = function(){console.log('aaa');},
    button1 = document.getElementById('button1'),
    button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
button1.onclick = button2.onclick = function(e) {
    publicFunc();
};

publicFunc = function(){console.log('bbb');};
```

To say the same thing in a different case (references to an object, and a function is an object)

```
var a = {prop: 2};
var b = a;
a = {anotherprop: 3};
// b still points to the original object {prop:2}
```

To get around that in this case, you have to add another level of indirection just like we did with the function;

```
var a = {indirection: {prop:2} };
var b = a;
a.indirection = {anotherprop: 3};
```

Lastly, this can only work with objects, that is it will never work with numbers, boolean or strings since they are always passed by value (unless you use the wrappers `new Number(), new String...`